# How to refresh list in react native every time the list is opened?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, token, use-effect

I was going through react-native tutorial and it finished in quite a raw state. Therefore, my app main list component does not refresh (except when first opened). Problem is that now my request to get the list items is in getToken operation:

```js
import { doGetItems } from '../services'

export default function List(props) {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    let token = null;

    const getToken = async() => {
        token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            doGetItems(token).then( jsonResp => setItems(jsonResp));
        } else {
            props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getToken();
    }, []);
```

This approach seems wrong overall. I have another problem passing the token to other components and this helps (kind of):
**EDIT** this actually makes it a lot better, it does update the list and token goes to other components (almost every time, but not always)

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getToken();
});
```

What would be the right way to handle the token? Also, how could I do request to get a new list every time the list is opened?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use useEffect hook, it will work like componentDidMount, here's the reference:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

You can store token in AsyncStorage and fetch it once app starts. Create a helper class which will do this work for you like:

```
class DataHandler {

 getTokenFromStorage() {
  this.token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
}

getToken() {
 return token;
}
}
export default new DataHandler();
```

In the start of app, call the getTokenFromStorage function so the token setups in the class, then you can get that token anywhere in the app using getToken function

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly I need more help. I'm new to this, so please do not judge too much. :) 

I've created helper like this:

`class TokenHandler {

    async getTokenFromStorage() {
        this.token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    }
   
    getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}

export default new TokenHandler();`


and call it like this: 

`useEffect(() => {
        TokenHandler.getTokenFromStorage();
    }, [])`

but I get the error: 

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_tokenHandler.TokenHandler.getTokenFromStorage')`

Comment: make sure you are importing it correct
`import TokenHandler from 'path'`

Answer (score 1):

`useFocusEffect` will trigger `getToken` each time the `List` component comes back into focus (see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/):

```js
import { doGetItems } from '../services'

export default function List(props) {

   const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

   useFocusEffect(
     useCallback(() => {
       const getToken = async() => {
         const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
         if (token) {
           doGetItems(token).then(jsonResp => setItems(jsonResp));
         } else {
           props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
         }
       };
       getToken();
     }, []),
   );

// rest of your component
```